# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException After Scanning NFC Tag

Tags: java, android, arrays, nfc

I'm attempting to rebuild my NFC Tag Reader

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071121/converting-existing-nfc-script-to-read-multiple-ndef-records

and I'm getting the following error:

```
 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
```

on the line:

```
 NdefMessage msg2 = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[1];
```

I understand the issue is usually related to trying to access an array item that doesn't exist however I'm really not sure how to resolve the issue in the following implementation.

P.S.

The issue only occurs when scanning a new NFC tag. I noticed something VERY interesting though...

If I comment out the following two lines the app does not crash AND scans the tag successfully!

```
// NdefMessage msg2 = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[1];


 //  beamMsg2.setText(new String(msg.getRecords()[1].getPayload()));
```

SOURCE:

```
public class Nfc extends Activity implements CreateNdefMessageCallback,
        OnNdefPushCompleteCallback {
    NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter;
    TextView beamMsg;
    TextView beamMsg2;
    private static final int MESSAGE_SENT = 1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.nfc);
        beamMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msg);
        beamMsg2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msg_ID);
        beamMsg.setText("Peter Smith");
        beamMsg2.setText("123456");

        // Check for available NFC Adapter
        mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        if (mNfcAdapter == null) {
            beamMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msg);
            beamMsg2= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msg_ID);

            beamMsg.setText("NFC is not available on this device.");
            beamMsg2.setText("NFC is not available on this device.");
        } else {
            // Register callback to set NDEF message
            mNfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessageCallback(this, this);
            // Register callback to listen for message-sent success
            mNfcAdapter.setOnNdefPushCompleteCallback(this, this);
        }
    }

    public void submitClicked(View v)
    {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.info,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }
    /**
     * Implementation for the CreateNdefMessageCallback interface
     */
    @Override
    public NdefMessage createNdefMessage(NfcEvent event) {
        NdefMessage msg = new NdefMessage(NdefRecord.createMime(
                beamMsg.getText()  .toString(), null));

        return msg;

    }

    public NdefMessage createNdefMessage_two(NfcEvent event) {
        NdefMessage msg2 = new NdefMessage(NdefRecord.createMime(
                beamMsg2.getText()  .toString(), null));

        return msg2;

    }




    /**
     * Implementation for the OnNdefPushCompleteCallback interface
     */
    @Override
    public void onNdefPushComplete(NfcEvent arg0) {
        // A handler is needed to send messages to the activity when this
        // callback occurs, because it happens from a binder thread
        mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_SENT).sendToTarget();
    }

    /** This handler receives a message from onNdefPushComplete */
    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case MESSAGE_SENT:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message sent!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Check to see that the Activity started due to an Android Beam
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
            processIntent(getIntent());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        // onResume gets called after this to handle the intent
        setIntent(intent);
    }

    /**
     * Parses the NDEF Message from the intent and prints to the TextView
     */
    void processIntent(Intent intent) {
        Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(
                NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
        // only one message sent during the beam
        NdefMessage msg = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[0];
        NdefMessage msg2 = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[1];
        // record 0 contains the MIME type, record 1 is the AAR, if present
        beamMsg.setText(new String(msg.getRecords()[0].getPayload()));
        beamMsg2.setText(new String(msg.getRecords()[1].getPayload()));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If NFC is not available, we won't be needing this menu
        if (mNfcAdapter == null) {
            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

   // @Override
   // public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    //    switch (item.getItemId()) {
      //      case R.id.menu_settings:
        //        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NFCSHARING_SETTINGS);
          //      startActivity(intent);
            //    return true;
         //   default:
           //     return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
       // }
    }
//}//}
```

EDIT AFTER ANSWER:

```
public class Connect extends Activity implements CreateNdefMessageCallback,
        OnNdefPushCompleteCallback {
    NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter;
    TextView beamMsg;
    TextView beamMsg2;
    private static final int MESSAGE_SENT = 1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.connect);
        beamMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msg);
        beamMsg2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msg_ID);
        beamMsg.setText("Peter Smith");
        beamMsg2.setText("123456");

        // Check for available NFC Adapter
        mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        if (mNfcAdapter == null) {
            beamMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msg);
            beamMsg2= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msg_ID);

            beamMsg.setText("NFC is not available on this device.");
            beamMsg2.setText("NFC is not available on this device.");
        } else {
            // Register callback to set NDEF message
            mNfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessageCallback(this, this);
            // Register callback to listen for message-sent success
            mNfcAdapter.setOnNdefPushCompleteCallback(this, this);
        }
    }

    public void submitClicked(View v)
    {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.info,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }
    /**
     * Implementation for the CreateNdefMessageCallback interface
     */
    @Override
    public NdefMessage createNdefMessage(NfcEvent event) {
        NdefMessage msg = new NdefMessage(NdefRecord.createMime(
                beamMsg.getText()  .toString(), null));

        return msg;

    }

    public NdefMessage createNdefMessage_two(NfcEvent event) {
        NdefMessage msg2 = new NdefMessage(NdefRecord.createMime(
                beamMsg2.getText()  .toString(), null));

        return msg2;

    }




    /**
     * Implementation for the OnNdefPushCompleteCallback interface
     */
    @Override
    public void onNdefPushComplete(NfcEvent arg0) {
        // A handler is needed to send messages to the activity when this
        // callback occurs, because it happens from a binder thread
        mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_SENT).sendToTarget();
    }

    /** This handler receives a message from onNdefPushComplete */
    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case MESSAGE_SENT:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message sent!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Check to see that the Activity started due to an Android Beam
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
            processIntent(getIntent());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        // onResume gets called after this to handle the intent
        setIntent(intent);
    }

    /**
     * Parses the NDEF Message from the intent and prints to the TextView
     */
    void processIntent(Intent intent) {
        Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(
                NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
    // only one message sent during the beam
    NdefMessage[] msg =  new NdefMessage[rawMsgs.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) {
        msg[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i];
        // record 0 contains the MIME type, record 1 is the AAR, if present
        beamMsg[i].setText(new String(msg[i].getRecords()[1].getPayload()));
        beamMsg2[i].setText(new String(msg[i].getRecords()[1].getPayload()));
    }}

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If NFC is not available, we won't be needing this menu
        if (mNfcAdapter == null) {
            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

   // @Override
   // public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    //    switch (item.getItemId()) {
      //      case R.id.menu_settings:
        //        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NFCSHARING_SETTINGS);
          //      startActivity(intent);
            //    return true;
         //   default:
           //     return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
       // }
    }
//}//}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is probably something to do with the intent you're sending to it on this line:

```
Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
```

Where is the code that you use to create the intent?

**Loop Edit:**

To add a loop more like this:

```
Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(
            NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
// only one message sent during the beam
NdefMessage[] msg = = new NdefMessage[rawMsgs.length];
for (int i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) {
    msg[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i];
    // record 0 contains the MIME type, record 1 is the AAR, if present
    beamMsg[i].setText(new String(msg[i].getRecords()[0].getPayload());
    beamMsg2[i].setText(new String(msg[i].getRecords()[1].getPayload()));
}
```

You will have to initialise beamMsg and beamMsg2 as an array of TextViews too. Or of course just append to the text field and leave as it is.

Comment: The issue only occurs when scanning a new NFC tag.
I noticed something VERY interesting though... 

If I comment out the following two lines the app does not crash AND scans the tag successfully! 

// NdefMessage msg2 = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[1];
 //  beamMsg2.setText(new String(msg.getRecords()[1].getPayload()));

Comment: It's still a problem with your intent, perhaps use a loop through each message up to the length of rawMsgs to prevent errors and still use all the messages. Then you will have a minimum of one and a max of length, additionally it's better not to hard code stuff like that.

Comment: Perhaps something such as:

     NdefMessage msg = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[0];
        
        while NdefMessage msg2 = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[1];
        {
         beamMsg2.setText(new String(msg.getRecords()[1].getPayload()));
        }
}

?

Comment: Excellent! (Thank you!) Eclipse just started generating a new error message: The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to TextView... Any idea what might be causing that? [I've updated my source code above]

Answer (score 0):

Actually, i not work with Java, but i will try.
Let me ask you, you can see the implementation of getParcelableArrayExtra(). Why he is returning only one message instead two?

Comment: The issue only occurs when scanning a new NFC tag.
I noticed something VERY interesting though... 

If I comment out the following two lines the app does not crash AND scans the tag successfully! 

// NdefMessage msg2 = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[1];
 //  beamMsg2.setText(new String(msg.getRecords()[1].getPayload()));